# how do i get rid of dict sign from a list in python?

Tags: python

So I have the code as follows:

```
[{'card_month': '10'}, {'card_year':'2011'}]
```

how do i get it to change from that to this

```
 ['card_month': '10', 'card_year':'2011']
```

Comment: `str(your_list).replace("{", "").replace("}", "")`. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Your second line is not valid Python. Try pasting it into the interpreter: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Why are you trying to do this???

Comment: thanks kevin for pointing that out..for a second..i thought it was valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
the_line_you_started_with = [{'card_month': '10'}, {'card_year':'2011'}]
new_dict = {}
new_dict.update(the_line_you_started_with[0])
new_dict.update(the_line_you_started_with[1])

print new_dict
```

the first line is your line(two dictionaries in a list), assigned to a variable

the second line creates a new dictionary

the third and fourth line update the new dictionary with indexed dictionaries from your first list

probably a cleaner way to do the 3rd and 4th line would be:

```
 for item in the_line_you_started_with:
       new_dict.update(item)
```

this way it wouldnt matter how many of them you got in `the_line_you_started_with`, all of them would get added to new_dict